# JS undefined: access primitive value of undefined without property?

Tags: javascript, reference, undefined, delete-operator, primitive

I'm learning JavaScript (JS). I came across that `undefined` (such as from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)) is a global property that refers to the `undefined` primitive value. I've seen this, for example, with the behavior of the `delete` operator:

When experimenting with the `delete` operator, I found that in non-strict mode:
`delete undefined`
evaluates to `false` (as opposed to `delete null` or another such attempted deletion of a primitive, which evaluates to `true`), whereas in strict-mode, it throws a `SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.`

My question is whether there is a way to access the "raw" `undefined` primitive value that the `undefined` property refers to in a way that can be directly written? For instance, when writing `undefined` in a JS program, that is actually referencing the global property whose value represents that primitive `undefined` value; I'm wondering if there is a way to directly write that `undefined` primitive value into a JS program, without going through such a reference? (For instance, like how `true` and `false` are Boolean primitives; can we actually write the `undefined` primitive in JS without accessing it via its same-named property?)

Comment: `(void 0)` is explicitly `undefined`

Comment: Similarly `({}.x)` is `undefined`